# TA1 Error in Availity EDI 278I Realtime Request for Prior Authorizations

Tags: biztalk, edi, real-time-data

I am trying to test the 278I Prior Authorization request with Availity and receiving a TA1 error in response.
I am using the following document for reference on the 278I request.
[EDI-278i-Companion-Guide-Non-HIPPA-005010X215.pdf](https://www.uhcprovider.com/content/dam/provider/docs/public/resources/edi/EDI-278i-Companion-Guide-Non-HIPPA-005010X215.pdf)

The format of the request is as follows:

**278 Inquiry Global ID - Request**
[image: 278 Inquiry Global ID - Request]

**Error from Availity in response**
[image: TA1 Error in 278 Response]

As per the documentation in few online articles and documents related to EDI Acknowledgement Errors, the line **TA1*768758654*221122*0040*R*013~** means: **Security Information Value is missing or incorrect.**

[image: Please see this image for more information on TA1 Error]

I have been trying to figure out the issue reason here for the past two days and couldn't get it to work. It would be really great if anyone could help or guide me to solve this issue or provide some useful information related to this issue.

Comment: Can you please post the payload and response as text, rather than images. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the ISA's length is exactly 106 characters and that both ISA2 and ISA4 contain exactly 10 characters/blanks. Also, ensure that there are no hidden symbols, such as tabs, CR/LFs anywhere inside the contents. CR/LFs are okay only after the segment terminator.